# Save Visual Studio Build Configuration

Tags: visual-studio, import, configuration, build, save

Currently I use Visual Studio 2013 and I want to use my own build configuration (like Debug or Release for example) which I've created in project A, in project B. Is there a possibility to save and import a build config in general and to use it in other projects?

Jonas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding, this is not possible directly, as the representation of the configuration is implicitly represented in the solution file (`*.sln`) and the project file (`*.vcproj`) by its name and conditions; however, similar to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563115/visual-studio-conditional-project-configuration-editor), the project files can be edited manually and similar parts can be factored out using the `Import` element, which is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx).